# Collision detection in andengine gles2

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm trying to set up Collision detection on the cactus-property items on all cactuses in the TMXmap example from andengine Gles2. I have tried various methods - can anyone give me one that works?

Original Code
[Tmxmaps andengine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/TMXTiledMapExample.java)

One suggested solution:
[collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055059/how-to-use-tmx-map-object-property-to-change-objects-behaviour?rq=1)

Another suggested solution:
[from andengine.org](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/tmx-collision-advice-t6787.html)

I've tried:

```
if(pTMXTileProperties.containsTMXProperty("cactus", "true")) {
    final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(pTMXTile.getTileX()+10, pTMXTile.getTileY(),14, 14);
    final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 1f);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody, boxFixtureDef);
    rect.setVisible(false);
    mScene.attachChild(rect);
}
```

This is from [AndEngine: Handling collisions with TMX Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940361/andengine-handling-collisions-with-tmx-objects)

But I get this error:

```
Physicsfactory not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the TMX example you have there as a basis for my game.

This is the main block of code for collisions:

// Define the block behavior

```
    mPathFinderMap = new IPathFinderMap<TMXLayer>(){

            private boolean mCollide;

            @Override
            public boolean isBlocked(final int pX, final int pY, final TMXLayer pTMXLayer) {
                /*
                 * This is where collisions happen and are detected 
                 */
                mCollide = false;
                //Null check. Used since not all tiles have properties
                if(pTMXLayer.getTMXTile(pX, pY).getTMXTileProperties(mTiledMap) != null){
                    //Get tiles with collision property
                    if(pTMXLayer.getTMXTile(pX, pY).getTMXTileProperties(mTiledMap).containsTMXProperty("COLLISION", "true")) 
                        mCollide = true;                                        
                }   

                if(mTMXmapLoader.getCollideTiles().contains(pTMXLayer.getTMXTile(pX, pY)))
                    mCollide = true;

                return mCollide;
            }

    };

/*
 * This method moves the sprite to the designated location
 */
public void walkTo(TMXTile pFinalPosition) {
    if(mHasFinishedPath){
        mHasFinishedPath = false;//This prevents overlapping paths when the user double clicks. Used to prevent stutter
        //Player coordinates
        final float[] lPlayerCordinates = mPlayerSprite.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(mPlayerSprite.getWidth()/2, mPlayerSprite.getHeight()/2);
        // Get the tile the center of the player are currently waking on. 
        TMXTile lPlayerPosition = SceneManager.mWorldScene.getTouchLayer().getTMXTileAt(lPlayerCordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_X], lPlayerCordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_Y]);
        mFinalPosition = pFinalPosition;

        // Sets the A* path from the player location to the touched location.
        if(mPathFinderMap.isBlocked(pFinalPosition.getTileColumn(), pFinalPosition.getTileRow(), SceneManager.mWorldScene.getTouchLayer())){    
            pFinalPosition = getNextTile(lPlayerPosition, pFinalPosition);
        }

        // These are the parameters used to determine the 
        int lFromCol = lPlayerPosition.getTileColumn(); int lFromRow = lPlayerPosition.getTileRow();
        int lToCol = pFinalPosition.getTileColumn();    int lToRow = pFinalPosition.getTileRow();
        boolean lAllowDiagonal = false;
        // Find the path. This needs to be refreshed
        AStarPath = mAStarPathFinder.findPath(MAX_SEARCH_DEPTH, mPathFinderMap, 0, 0, mTiledMap.getTileColumns() - 1, mTiledMap.getTileRows() - 1, SceneManager.mWorldScene.getTouchLayer(), 
                lFromCol, lFromRow, lToCol, lToRow, lAllowDiagonal, mHeuristic, mCostCallback);

        //Log.i("AstarPath", "AStarPath  " + AStarPath);
        //Only loads the path if the AStarPath is not null
        Path lPlayerPath = loadPathFound();
        //Log.i("AstarPath", "lPlayerPath  " + lPlayerPath);
        if(lPlayerPath != null)
            moveSprite(lPlayerPath);//Moves the sprite along the path
        else
            mHasFinishedPath = true;//If the path is null the player has not moved. Set the flag to true allows input to effect the sprite
    }else{
        //Update parameters
        mFinalPosition = pFinalPosition;
        mWaypointIndex = 0;
    }
}

/*
 * Updates the path
 */
public void updatePath(TMXTile pFinalPosition) {    
    //Player coordinates
    final float[] lPlayerCordinates = mPlayerSprite.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(mPlayerSprite.getWidth()/2, mPlayerSprite.getHeight()/2);
    // Get the tile the feet of the player are currently waking on. 
    TMXTile lPlayerPosition = SceneManager.mWorldScene.getTouchLayer().getTMXTileAt(lPlayerCordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_X], lPlayerCordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_Y]);

    // Sets the A* path from the player location to the touched location.
    if(mPathFinderMap.isBlocked(pFinalPosition.getTileColumn(), pFinalPosition.getTileRow(), SceneManager.mWorldScene.getTouchLayer())){    
        pFinalPosition = getNextTile(lPlayerPosition, pFinalPosition);
    }

    // Determine the tile locations
    int FromCol = lPlayerPosition.getTileColumn();
    int FromRow = lPlayerPosition.getTileRow();
    int ToCol = pFinalPosition.getTileColumn();
    int ToRow = pFinalPosition.getTileRow();
    // Find the path. This needs to be refreshed
    AStarPath = mAStarPathFinder.findPath(MAX_SEARCH_DEPTH, mPathFinderMap, 0, 0, mTiledMap.getTileColumns()-1, mTiledMap.getTileRows()-1, SceneManager.mWorldScene.getTouchLayer(), 
            FromCol, FromRow, ToCol, ToRow, false, mHeuristic, mCostCallback);

    //Loads the path with the astar specifications
    Path lPlayerPath = loadPathFound();
    //Moves the sprite along the path
    if(lPlayerPath != null){
        moveSprite(lPlayerPath);
    }else{
        //If the path is still null after the path manipulation then the path is finished
        mHasFinishedPath = true;
        mWaypointIndex = 0;
        //mPlayerSprite.stopAnimation();
        //AStarPath = null;
    }
}
```

The TMXmapLoader does the rest:

```
//Get the collision, ext, and changing tiles from the object sets on the map
    mCollideTiles = this.getObjectGroupPropertyTiles("COLLIDE",  TMXGroupObjects);  
    mExitTiles = this.getObjectPropertyTiles("EXIT", mTMXObjects);
    mChangingTiles = this.getObjectGroupPropertyTiles("CHANGE", TMXGroupObjects);
...
public ArrayList<TMXTile> getCollideTiles(){
    return mCollideTiles;       
}
...
public ArrayList<TMXTile> getObjectGroupPropertyTiles(String pName, final int pLayer, ArrayList<TMXObjectGroup> pTMXObjectGroups){
    ArrayList<TMXTile> ObjectTile = new ArrayList<TMXTile>();
    for (final TMXObjectGroup pObjectGroups : pTMXObjectGroups) {
        // Iterates through the properties and assigns them to the new variable
        for (final TMXObjectGroupProperty pGroupProperties : pObjectGroups.getTMXObjectGroupProperties()) {
            //Sees if any of the elements have this condition
            if (pGroupProperties.getName().contains(pName)) {
                for (final TMXObject pObjectTiles : pObjectGroups.getTMXObjects()) {
                    int ObjectX = pObjectTiles.getX();
                    int ObjectY = pObjectTiles.getY();
                    // Gets the number of rows and columns in the object
                    int ObjectRows = pObjectTiles.getHeight() / WorldActivity.TILE_HEIGHT;
                    int ObjectColumns = pObjectTiles.getWidth() / WorldActivity.TILE_WIDTH;

                    for (int TileRow = 0; TileRow < ObjectRows; TileRow++) {
                        for (int TileColumn = 0; TileColumn < ObjectColumns; TileColumn++) {
                            float lObjectTileX = ObjectX + TileColumn * WorldActivity.TILE_WIDTH;
                            float lObjectTileY = ObjectY + TileRow * WorldActivity.TILE_HEIGHT;
                            ObjectTile.add(mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(pLayer).getTMXTileAt(lObjectTileX, lObjectTileY));                       
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    return ObjectTile;
}
```

Comment: Hey, so are you basically making an array of the coordinates of the special tiles and creating rectangles objects over them in order to deal with collisions?

Comment: Kind of. An array of coordinates of special tiles, yes. Rectangles? no. There's actually no box2d physics at all in this code. You can use isBlocked() to figure out if a target tile is a collision object. But once set up, You can just make a collision layer in Tiled, and the code will handle the collision of those tiles as the player walks around.

Comment: Do you have a working example of this I could download / checkout

Comment: Ask and you shall receive, http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/tiled-game-updated-t4331.html

Comment: Was that helpful at all?

Comment: Just home from work will test tommorow - looks like I need to load the modified version of andengine for this from the page?

Comment: Correct, but all of my other projects have worked just fine with it still.

Comment: have you tried creating enemy characters / expanding this etc

Comment: I'm still working on it but I've added a HUD with live health bar, currency, basic Npcs, basic quest, and basic shop. Enemies are coming in a day or so. I haven't decided how to make the fight system yet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with android development, but the error seems to indicate that `PhysicsFactory` hasn't been imported. Maybe try adding an import statement like this to the top of your file?

```
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
```

Comment: will test this out when I get home